# What is the purpose of a `SharedFlowSlot` inside the `SharedFlowImpl` class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

I am trying to understand how a `Flow` works by looking at the `SharedFlowImpl` class. As the `Flow` interface ensures that all classes which implement `Flow` must override the `collect` method, it seemed like the obvious choice of method to peruse first. On the first line of the `collect` method we have `val slot = allocateSlot()` where slot is of type `SharedFlowSlot`.

From looking at the code, I can surmise the following:

1. There is a 1:1 correspondence between the number of collectors and the number of `SharedFlowSlot`.
2. A collector is equivalent to the number of subscribers which is equivalent to the number of times `collect` is called.
3. The index property inside the `SharedFlowSlot` serves as the index of the flow value to be emitted to the collector and it is initialised as the `replayIndex`.

Am I going along the right lines?